# RIA Services domain service factory in web.config

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have created a WCF RIA Services Class Library project which has a custom IDomainServiceFactory. Normally I would hook this up in Application_Start or something in a ASPNET project but this service will also be used by third parties via a SOAP endpoint so I need a way to create it automatically.

Only way I can think of is via web.config. Is this possible? I can't seem to find any documentation on domain services configuration settings.

Comment: Isn't the ASP.NET solution still sufficient? Even if you add a SOAP endpoint to the service, the service is hosted in ASP.NET, right?

Comment: Hmm, you're right, its got to be hosted under ASP.NET anyway. Mustn't have been thinking that day.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this programmatically in this fashion:

```
public void SomeConfigurationMethod()
{
    DomainService.Factory = new YourDomainServiceFactory();
}
```